# Как удалить всё, что после запятой с помощью regex?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

В числе с запятой нужно удалить всё после запятой с помощью регулярки. Сейчас такой код: `data.split(',')[0].replace(' ', '')`. Написал на регулярке `data = re.sub(r',\d+', '', data)`,однако выводит это: `8067\xa0`. В чём проблема?

Comment: print(int("8067\xa0"))
print("8067\xa0".strip())

Comment: `\xa0` - это неразрывный пробел, его тоже нужно удалять заменой или ещё как